# Code will be never executed warning occurs in while loop

Tags: c

Hello I'm working on my personal project. The code takes input from a user then checks the validity through the ValidateInput function calling.

Here is the code for your visuality.

I marked the code lines that causes warning.

My intention is to understand what is the problem of my code, and what is the situation of my code now

Could you explain this??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int ValidateUser(char *);
int ValidateInput(int);
FILE *database;

struct{
  int year;
  int unit;
  float gpa;
  char semester;
  char grade;
  char name[40];
}student;

int ValidateInput(int x)
{
   while ( x!=1 || x!=2 || x!=3) // 2. I want to validate the wrong input untill user enters right answer
   {
     printf("Please enter correct choice"};
     scan("%d",&x);
     if( x == 1 || x==2 || x==3)
      {
       break;
      }
    return 0;
}

int ValidateUser(char *input)
{
    int result;
    result = strcmp(input, student.name);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (result != 0)
        {
            printf("The Username you entered does not exit. Please enter correct name.\n");
            ValidateUser(input);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{

  printf("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\t|\t\t\t\t Santa Monica College\t\t\t\t\t |\n");
  printf("\t----------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
  printf("\t\tWelcome to Santa Monica Student Record System.\n\n");
  printf("Please Enter Your Option\n");
  printf("\t1.View GPA/GRADE\n");
  printf("\t2.Add New GPA\n");
  printf("\t3.Modify Information\n");
    
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    char UserName[40];
    
    if(choice == 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter your name\n");
        scanf("%s", UserName);
        ValidateUser(UserName);
        printf("The GPA of %s is %f , %c ", student.name, student.gpa, student.grade);
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        printf("Please enter your name\n");
        scanf("%s", UserName);
        ValidateUser(UserName);
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        printf("Please enter your name\n");
        scanf("%s", UserName);
        ValidateUser(UserName);
    }
    else
    {
        ValidateInput(choice); // 1.pass the value to function
    }
 
  
  return 0;
}
```

So to my understanding is that the code takes the choice from the user, then it passes the input value to the validation function to check it. But It seems like the warning is saying the situation for validation function doesn't exit

Comment: That while-loop expression will always be true. `x` cannot simultaneously be three different values. If x ==1, it cannot possible be 2 or 3, and therefore all three conditions combined with logical OR will be true; *always*. Unrelated, `scan` is probably supposed to be `scanf`, but I suspect you won't see that problem until you try linking this thing after ignoring the "implicit function `scan` returning `int`" warning.

Comment: Think of a number between 1 and 3. OK, let's assume you chose 2. Does 2 equal 1? Does 2 equal 3? Then think about what `x != 1 || x != 2 || x != 3` will be.

Comment: My compiler (MSVC) even tells me what to do: *warning C6289: Incorrect operator:  mutual exclusion over || is always a non-zero constant.  Did you intend to use && instead?*

Comment: Understood. If user enters none of option above, it's always be true right? So that's why I should put && operator. Because  If user enters 1, it's still not 2. Thanks for the helps !!!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the ending bracket to your while loop, and you accidentally put a bracket instead of a parentheses on your `printf()`

Code in `ValidateInput()` should be this:

```
while ( x!=1 || x!=2 || x!=3)
   {
     printf("Please enter correct choice");
     scan("%d",&x);
     if( x == 1 || x==2 || x==3)
      {
       break;
      }
   }
   return 0;
```

It would also be appreciated if you gave us the error as well, since it makes our jobs a lil' bit easier